# Does Apache Camel support Fabric?

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, fuseesb

I am a beginner to Camel, and only recently I have become familiar with Camel EIPs.

So far all my test projects use sockets or HTTP endpoints; each client wishing to communicate with another server (or service) needs to know all the available network addresses of each implementation (e.g. a list of protocols, host name & ports).

To fix this, I remembered a suggestion made by a user here, that pointed me to Camel Fabric. According to the Fuse documentation, it

> (...) provides a way to reuse Fabric's discovery mechanism to expose physical socket &  HTTP endpoints into the runtime registry using a logical name (...)

[Quote Source](http://fuse.fusesource.org/fabric/docs/overview.html#Camel_Fabric)

However, I have not found any living examples on how to use this in the Camel in Action book, nor on the Internet. Everything I find requires JBoss tools and Fuse.

Consequently I have a question:

1. Does Camel support this feature? If yes, where can I find an example in Java DSL to study?

Comment: Fabric is a Jboss Fuse feature. I dint think Camek will support it. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuse Fabric is an open source project

- http://fuse.fusesource.org/fabric/

And the source code is at github:

- https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fuse

Fuse Fabric is part of the JBoss Fuse product, and Fabric supports Camel, as it has some Camel components and extensions.

There is some Fabric Camel documentation at:

- http://fuse.fusesource.org/fabric/docs/overview.html#Camel_Fabric

And some examples in the source code:

- https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fuse/tree/master/fabric/fabric-examples

Though to get the benefit from Fabric is really for end users of JBoss Fuse. You can compile the source code and use as you want - its ASL2 licensed. Though we package and include it in our JBoss Fuse product(s).

Fabric is much more than a number of Camel components / extensions. For example James Strachan did a video demo of Camel in the cloud with Fabric at CamelOne 2013 conference earlier this year. The video is here: http://vimeo.com/68442425

The web consule used for the video demo, is hawtio

- http://hawt.io/

Which is another ASL2 licensed open source project, that is also out of the box in JBoss Fuse (6.1 onwards).

So the answer is yes. Its Fabric which supports Camel. 
Apache Camel from ASF does not have Fabric, as Fabric is not an ASF project.